# How to find out which is a source and which is destination from list of mirth channels?

Tags: mirth

I have 9 channels in my Mirth connect I want to know their order and their source and destination.
The source of one channel is the detinatio0n for other . How can I found out that.

I am new for this server so I don't have any idea for their order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Tags" to have a better overview.To define Tags you have to go to the settings. You can also create groups or name the channels to have a better order. In the Dashboard you have the oportunity to right click on

[image]

There are options like Collapse and Expand All